# basic charting tool in R for analysis of trading systems

Tags: r

I have started learning R and have got a grasp of it. I have read some books which are meant for R beginners

I want to use R for analysis of trading systems. Following are my requirements. I would be thankful if someone can guide me as to what should I read for the following things?

1: Making a basic charting tool. If I plot a candlestick chart, Assuming the data is large, How can I move a chart from left to right using a scroll bar, How can I zoom in and zoom out charts? How can I control the parameters of the output from the graph itself? Basically what is the best package that I should use to do these things in R

2: How to convert R code into C or Java or C#? I want to do this to integrate real time financial data as well as automatic execution of strategies

3: The packaging concepts? How to make packages in R?

Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but is a request for reading suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Can't, apparently, post more than two links, so you'll need to google some of it ;p. So, in order:

1. It sounds like you want [manipulate](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/manipulate), which is pretty integrated with RStudio (if you don't use RStudio, you really should);
2. You can't directly convert, although R does ultimately compile down to C, and R objects are a set of SEXPs within C. However, what you can do is integrate all of those languages (and, if you really want, Fortran). For C, you have the .C foreign function caller (type ?.C in the REPL to read the manual around it), and for C++, Dirk Eddelbuettel's wonderful package RCpp. I thoroughly recommend Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R Programming" book (just google it), which contains sections on both. For Java, foreign integration is provided by the rJava package.
3. Wickham's book has a section on this; there's also the ['Writing R Extensions'](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual that constitutes part of the standard R documentation. Whichever you use, RStudio (again) has pretty tight integration with the devtools package and roxygen (think of it as the R version of doxygen), both of which make it a lot easier to build, standardise and test the compilation of R packages.

Comment: Thank You very much. I will definitely look at it

Answer (score 1):

No easy answers for the first two question. For the third one:

`package.skeleton('mypackage')`

would give you a simple example of R package structure.